How do I teach my dog that it isn't just a suggestion to come when called?
My 4-year-old Great Pyrenees is not very good at coming when called. In other regards the dog is pretty responsive: She's obedient and well-behaved.
When we let her out in to the fenced in back yard, we usually leave the back door open a bit and she comes back into the house when she's ready to do so. Usually, that's fine with my wife and I.
Sometimes, we need her to come in sooner than she'd like and we've all tried calling her in (me, my wife, son, daughter, son-in-law, etc.) and, once in a while on rare occasions, that works, but usually, if we go to the door and call her to the house she declines our invitation or "hides" behind a tree or bush in the yard. (That's quite funny to see a big dog thinking she's hiding behind a skinny tree.)
The interesting part of this is our grandson is able, every time, to just say, in a conversational tone, (sometimes just through an open window) "Hey, get in the house" and she immediately stops what she's doing and happily trots into the house. She doesn't seem to have any particular "connection" with our grandson other than this particular "interaction". He doesn't offer any reward or encouragement to her. He just tells her to get in the house, she comes in, and they both go about their own business.
What's going on here, and how might we duplicate this behavior so that she comes into the house immediately for the rest of us?
I see similar questions posted, regarding how to teach the dog to come when called, etc. and she has been "trained" to come when called reliably when in the house, so she knows what we're asking her to do. I'm curious why she responds so differently for my grandson than the rest of us when she's outside.

I'm going to make one fairly standard solution: have you and the dog, together, taking a dog training class. In addition to teaching the dog how to respond more reliably, these classes teach the human how to give signals that are more consistent and easier for the dog to understand. Might be worth the investment.

@keshlam Thanks. We've done that and she was very receptive to it all. I've had dogs all my life and trained them quite successfully, This doesn't seem to be a simple training issue.

I think you need to understand the situation from your dogs perspective:

When she's outside, she's having fun, sniffing around, doing whatever.
When you call her, she knows what you expect of her. She also knows that her time in the back yard will be over once she comes to you. That's exactly why she tries hiding.
After you call her, she'll have to be inside and cannot sniff around and have fun anymore. She expects being inside to be more boring than being outside.

From that perspective, you're a spoilersport who's cutting her fun short. For what reward? What are you offering in return to make it more interesting to come inside?
I have no idea what your grandson is offering her. Maybe some play time or tasty treats? Only you could answer that.
That's also the key to recalling her reliably. You have to offer her something in return for her obedience. The easiest thing you can offer is verbal praise. Start praising her as soon as she makes the first few steps to you. Continue praising her until she is at your side. For most dogs, praise alone is not enough, though.
When she comes to you, you'll have to offer something to her that she thinks is better than hiding away to stay outside. That can be a tasty treat, but some dogs are more interested in a play session or cuddles. (For example, many police dogs or drug sniffer dogs are rewarded with a short game of tug-of-war instead of food.) You'll have to determine what your dog likes most and give her a reward she values more than staying outside.
Another alternative is to change the way you recall her. From your description it sounds like you stand in the door, call your dog and expect her to come running to you. From her perspective, if she "hides" behind a skinny tree, she doesn't have to come running to you. Try "collecting" her from her tree instead. Walk up to her, showing her very clearly that you can see her, then say the command to follow you and walk inside together with her. If she doesn't follow you, Keep your body directed towards the house, but look over your shoulder at her. This is dog language for "follow me" and should reinforce the verbal command you gave her earlier.

+1 That is proof again that things (information) can be hidden in plain sight. And you revealed several of them - regarding dog psychology :) Tnx.

",,,I have no idea what your grandson is offering her. Maybe some play time or tasty treats...."  That's just it... nothing. He pays very little attention to her, he basically just "walks by" and says "Get in the house." and she does, happily. They don't interact that much otherwise. I'm the play and treats guy... which she's happy to accept once she's in the house.

A lovely dog.
But as you probably know "This breed is ancient, dating back thousands of years. The Great Pyrenees dates back to the Bronze Age. Which, for those of us who didn’t pay attention during history lessons at school, is 1800 – 1000 B.C"
As a rule, 'Ancient dogs' are notoriously independent and can struggle to learn commands that they follow regularly. But like a good hunting dog, when learned, they are often the best at following the command.
Also their purpose was to guard sheep against wolves and bears, with very little support. So yes a relatively young (still has puppy urges), Ancient breed dog, breed to be independent and hardcore, isnt going to always be easy to train. You are going to need patience.
PS 'ancient breeds'  typically have a lot more in common with wolf behavior than most modern breeds.  Wolves cannot be trained, and some ancient breeds are a close second to not paying attention. So you are going to have to have a lot of patience if you want more than rudimentary commands, when they are young.
This question does come under the banner of dog training, and you can take weekly lessons at either volunteer organizations or pay a dog trainer to sort it, but initially I would recommend dog treat training.  Of course your dog needs to be motivated by food, and you need to find the ONE or two treats that it will do anything to get.  I recommend a single ingredient meat based dog treat, that you can have in small amounts and keep on you while retraining the recall.
Follow youtube clips if you like, but the dog treat method is 101 when it comes to getting most dogs to work with you. If you can find something they really love, and they associated the recall with the treat, and coming to you, you are 90% of the way towards increasing that bond and percentage success of recall.
Things to note.  You have to restrict the specific treat that you use for recall ONLY for recall. Everyone who interacts with your dog should be aware NOT to use that treat, otherwise it becomes lower value and you have wasted your advantage. When they do come, and you get them to sit for a few seconds, and then feed them the treat, give them the pats and the love.  Make it a celebration for them, release their endorphins.
The same treat can also be used to get your dog to walk loose lead right next to you for long treks. Just having it in your hand, and their gaze and nose focusing on it, but you only giving it to them in very small amounts every ten minutes or so can assist the walking process.
Just suggestions that I have seen work, and much easier for most people than jumping to more advanced training like clicker or word association alone.
Good luck. b

All this makes good sense. She's not really into food that much. She'll eat it if I give it to her, but she doesn't necessarily get up and cross the room for any food. Not a motivator really. We've put a lot of work into training, etc. and she's pretty good with most of it.... for a Pyr. My question is more oriented to how does the grandson get her to come in with no hesitation at all. He doesn't offer her treats, take time to play with her more than the rest of us, etc. She just "believes" him.... I wonder how that works.

He is closer to her size, which may mean that she thinks of him as her generation of the pack and that what he is doing is more likely to be interesting than what you are doing. Or maybe something in intonation or body language that she is picking up on. Or it may just be that visits from him are special and fun for that reason; she can see you any day. (Think of when you were a kid and a visit from relatives was exciting even if they were boring old adults.)
